# Time-Driven triggers not working properly

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

We're working with Spreadsheets and Apps-Script to do some automation, therefore we've set up some time based triggers, some hourly, some daily based, all set up in the apps-script dashboard. It happens more and more often, that the triggers simply don't run. They're just not executed, so I don't see any failure in the dashboard (because the code is valid, though).

I thought, it was about the .getActiveSpreadSheet() method which might not work, when the sheet is not open or visible (which it would be in the most cases), but I recently have a sheet where I open it by id (openById), and the trigger still works just as he pleases.

Simple example code is:

```
function testTrigger(){
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById($sheetid).getSheetByName("ha")
 sheet.getRange("A1").setValue(new Date());
  Logger.log("test");
}
```

And before I used

```
function testTrigger(){
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("ha")
 sheet.getRange("A1").setValue(new Date());
  Logger.log("test");
}
```

The trigger for this function is set to fire every minute. As I can see in the sheet, the last time it ran was 12:35:48, but it's now 12:40. So why isn't it working?

By the time I'm writing this, it suddenly fired at 12:40:48. But now it's 12:44 again, so there are already 3 runs missing! Why does this keep happening?

And: Would SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("ha") even work with a closed sheet? Has the sheet to be open AND active in the browser? We were using Spreadsheets and Apps-Script for months now, I used getActiveSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("ha") every time and it worked. It seems, the time driven triggers are buggy atm, I have no other conclusion (since the code and everything else is valid).

Is there any way to find out, why a trigger didn't fire (beside a code error, which I would of course see in the dashboard).
And would these problems also occur, if I would use programmatical triggers?

Thanks in advance!

Here's an image of the problem (nothing changed in the code or in the trigger during these runs):
[image]

Answer (score 2):

**To answer some your questions**

1. As specified by the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) for time-driven triggers "The time may be slightly randomized — for example, if you create a recurring 9 a.m. trigger, Apps Script chooses a time between 9 a.m. and 10 a.m"
2. If instead you create manually a [ClockTriggerBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder) with the parameter `nearMinute(minute)`, this "Specifies the minute at which the trigger runs (plus or minus 15 minutes)". In other words: You cannot expect from the Apps Script triggers to run precisely at the time you would like them to.
3. `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` works if you have a bound script, rather than an alone-standing script. In any case, to avoid error sources, it is wise to use `SpreadsheetApp.openById(id)` instead of `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()`
4. You can supervise your triggers und [executions](https://script.google.com/home/executions) and [My triggers](https://script.google.com/home/triggers), however from your description it seems like the trigger is fired correctly, just not exactly at the time you would desire.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but did you see the picture? If I set up the trigger by dashboard or programmatically to fire every minute, then of course it has to fire every(!) minute! I really don't care at which second during the minute. But as you can see, it simply hasn't fired. This is just for testing, I have others set up to fire every hour and they also sometimes don't work. And I don't see, why they weren't executed. Like I mentioned, checking the executions and my triggers is pointless, since there was nothing executed in the first place (and as you can see in the picture).

Comment: I tried to point out in my answer that even if you set a time trigger to fire each minute, it not necessary does so - as specified by Google, there can be a significant delay. From your explanation and screenshot I assume that you have no failed executions, only executions that do not fire on time? Reproducing your sample on a time-based trigger I do not encounter any problems. Maybe there is some other issue, e.g. an interference with other triggers? Keep in mind that there are limits like e.g. for Triggers total runtime per day https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

Comment: Sure, I get it. And thats exactly the point: I don't see the executions, because they were simply not executed/ triggered. And this occurs also with different triggers that should fire every hour (so its not limited to the 1 minute triggers, which I just used to test the real trigger behaviour). So there are no failed attempts. Even if we would run into limits, we should get exceptions, like written in your article (Exception messages). But there are none. So I don't have the slightest clue, where the error occurs.

Comment: How many different time trigger do you have in total and was is the total daily runtime? If you have a consumer account and your total trigger run time (for all triggers related to your account) is more than 90 minutes per day, some executions might simply be skipped without throwing an exception.

Comment: We use Gsuite Business, so I don't think, we exceed the quota here. And I'm also pretty sure, that I don't have more than 20 triggers for each script (that'd be bad in every way). The thing is, that I don't know, why it's not executing. Have another script running every hour, which executed today at 04:28, 05:28, 07:28, 08:28. So 06:28 is just missing. And of course, there's no error in the executions, it's simply not there. But I will clean up some older stuff, scripts, triggers etc, maybe this helps. Is there any way to check my current qutoa? I couldn't find anything in this regard.

Comment: If nothing helps - it might be a bug. Similar issues have already been reported: https://issuetracker.google.com/36764946 https://issuetracker.google.com/130783486

Comment: Yeah, I already reported 2 bugs in the last time regarding this. The problem in your link is, that the created trigger simply disappears, which is not the case in my dashboard. It simply doesn't fire. Stupid enough, that even if we would exceed the quota, google seems to not inform us about it.