# Monthly Sheet Duplication via Time Trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, time, triggers, archive

I have a spreadsheet to track monthly memberships and payments. I duplicate the sheet at the end of the month rename it to the date and lock it to archive it. I have a marco recorded and setup to do this and have a button on the sheet to click to do this. It works great.

However, I'd like to make this script triggered via time which I have setup in the Tigger area of google scripts. But when it runs, it fails and I get the following error:

Exception: Please select an active sheet first.
at ArchiveSheet(macros:5:15)

Here is my code:

```
function ArchiveSheet() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
spreadsheet.duplicateActiveSheet();
var sheetname = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MMM/yyyy");
spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setName("Archive "+ sheetname);
spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Current Month'), true);
spreadsheet.getRange('J3:J263').activate();
};
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`getActiveSpreasheet()` can only be used on bounded scripts or on change, on edit and on open installable triggers created programmatically, on a time-driven trigger you have to use one of the following

- `open(file)` (this should be used together with DriveApp / Advanced Drive Service
- `openById(id)`
- `openByUrl(url)`

Related

- [Time-Driven triggers not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59175431/1595451)

Comment: Thanks. How do I properly implement this? I tried but got authentication issues? Which I don't understand how to work.

If I'm doing this right, I think I just have to add: 

`var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("sheetid");//sheetid gets replaced with the right sheet id`

to the top and the rest should work yes?

Answer (score 0):

#### Sheet Duplication with a trigger

```
function myfunk101() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  sh.activate();
  const nsh = ss.duplicateActiveSheet();
  const n = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "HH:mm:ss");
  nsh.setName("Archive " + n);
};
```

The active sheet is always ss.getSheets()[0] so it's better to pick on by name.  And it won't activate a sheet on a current session because the instance its running on is only opened on the server.

```
function createTriggerFormyfunk101() {
  if (ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == 'myfunk101').length == 0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('myfunk101').timeBased().everyMinutes(5).create();//I used every five minutes because I didn't want to wait for the end of the month
  }
}
```

**I think this is a better way to go:**

```
function myfunk101() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");//Pick your sheet
  ss.insertSheet(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "HH:mm:ss"), {template: sh});//change you time format for your name.  Since I was running 5 minute triggers I wanted more precision.
};
```

- [insertSheet(sheetName, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertSheet(String,Object))

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 

First set of code seems to make the most sense to me with what I'm trying to do, just a month archive of the sheet. 

That said, when I try it out the `sh.active();`fails the script.

Comment: There is no method active().  Both methods worked for me so I can't help you much if you can't get it work unless you can provide a specific error message and line number.